# Displaying how many times x number was picked out of a 500 random pool of numbers

Tags: python

I want to pick 500 cards randomly out of a standard 52-card deck and display how many times the Ace of Diamonds was picked. I am not sure how to loop it and make it randomly pick 500 cards. What I have tried just resulted in the same card being picked 500 times. This is currently what I have:

```
import random

card_number = random.randint(0,52)
card_value = card_number % 13
card_suit = card_number // 13
ace = 0
print(card_value, card_suit)

if card_value == 0:
    card_value = "A"
if card_suit == 0:
    card_suit = "♥"
if card_value == 1:
    card_value = "K"
if card_suit == 1:
    card_suit = "♠"
if card_value == 12:
    card_value = "Q"
if card_suit == 2:
    card_suit = "♦"
if card_value == 11:
    card_value = "J"
if card_suit == 3:
    card_suit = "♣"
if card_value == 0 and card_suit == 2:
    ace = ace + 1
card = str(card_value) + str(card_suit)
print(card)
    
print("The Ace of Diamonds has appeared", ace , "times")
```

Comment: Start with `for i in range(500):` to iterate 500 times.

Comment: You have to get a new random number each time you loop it. Specifically you should place the random int declaration at the top of the loop `card_number = random.randint(0,52)` as this is where you are getting the actual number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate 500 times to pick 500 cards and check the results of each card. Since the number of iterations does not affect any output, the dummy variable `_` can be used as the iterator.

```py
aces = 0

for _ in range(500):
    card_number = random.randint(0,52)
    card_value = card_number % 13
    card_suit = card_number // 13
    ...
```

---

Now, since you only care about the number of time Ace of Diamonds is drawn from the deck, there is no need to check for every suit and value combination. Instead, only check if the suit is Diamonds (2) and the value is Ace (0). (You can also use the built-in function `divmod(x, y)`, which returns `x // y, x % y`.)

```py
diamond_aces = 0

for _ in range(500):
    card_number = random.randint(0, 52)
    card_suit, card_value = divmod(card_number, 13)
    if card_suit == 2 and card_value == 0:
        diamond_aces += 1
```

*The condition `if card_suit == 2 and card_value == 0:` can be substituted with any of the following (not a comprehensive list):*

- `if (card_suit, card_value) == (2, 0):`
- `if divmod(card_number, 13) == (2, 0):`
- `if divmod(random.randint(0, 52), 13) == (2, 0):`

However, if `divmod(card_number, 13) == (2, 0)` evaluates to `True`, then the condition `2 * 13 + 0 == card_number` (26) must be `True`, by the inverse of `divmod()`. So this can be further simplified to:

```py
diamond_aces = 0

for _ in range(500):
    if random.randint(0, 52) == 26:
        diamond_aces += 1
```

Or, for the list comprehension enthusiasts out there:

```py
diamond_aces = [True for _ in range(500) if random.randint(0, 52) == 26].count(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't really need all those if conditions in the middle if your focus is only the Aces of Diamonds! Your code can be modified as follows:

```
import random
ace = 0
for i in range(500):
  card_number = random.randint(0,52)
  card_value = card_number % 13
  card_suit = card_number // 13
  
  if card_value == 0 and card_suit == 2: #This is where the main Ace of Diamonds check is happening
      ace = ace + 1
print("The Ace of Diamonds has appeared", ace , "times")
```